# Can I make a Customizer dropdown-pages list include private pages?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I'm using the following code to add a field to the Customizer where the user can select a page from the available pages on the site:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'resources_page', array(
    'type' => 'dropdown-pages',
    'section' => 'key_page_locations',
    'label' => 'Resources page',
    'description' => 'A page for private resources'
) );
```

The theme then uses this field's value in various places to show links to the Resources page. But the Resources page is (intentionally) private, so it doesn't show in the dropdown-pages list. Can I force the list to allow a private page to be selected here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem any way to hook into the underlying `get_pages` call that the control `dropdown-pages` uses, so you'll have to build your own set of choices (that includes private pages) and use the standard `select` control type instead:

```php
if ( ! class_exists( 'WPSE_406789_Walker_Page_Options' ) ) {
    class WPSE_406789_Walker_Page_Options extends Walker_Page {
        public $choices = [];

        public function start_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = [], $current_object_id = 0 ) {
            $pad = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', $depth * 3 );

            $this->choices[ $data_object->ID ] = $pad . get_the_title( $data_object );
        }
    }
}

$walker = new WPSE_406789_Walker_Page_Options();

$pages = get_pages([
    'post_status' => [
        'publish',
        'private',
    ],
]);

$walker->walk( $pages, 0, [], 0 );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'resources_page', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'choices' => $walker->choices,
    'section' => 'key_page_locations',
    'label' => 'Resources page',
    'description' => 'A page for private resources',
]);
```

I've used a custom walker here so that you still get the `&nbsp;` padding that the default `wp_dropdown_pages` generates to visualise the page hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems to work perfectly, and looks just like the dropdown-pages version. No one will ever know. :D